# Date comparison always returns false using textfield with type date

Tags: javascript, date

I have been trying to compare two dates. pdate is fetched from html using getElementById tag where as other is generated using js Date() class. Whenever I convert them it checks out as false all the time.

```
var whatNow = new Date();
//pdate is value fetched using javascript from type=date textfield
//console.log(pdate) prints (2017-5-25) which is current 
if(pdate >= whatNow.getFullYear()+'-'+(whatNow.getMonth()+1)+'-
    '+whatNow.getDate()){
//selected date is greater than or equals to current date. Good to do code.
else {
//this code runs always no matter what I do.
}
```

Comment: There is also [valueAsDate](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-valueasdate). But in general Date input is not supported in [Safari, FF, IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Comment: What is the format of the text field? If you use ISO 8601 format dates they can be compared using [*String.prototype.localeCompare()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings, which can lead to bugs. Compare `Date`s instead:

```
if (new Date() >= new Date(pdate+"T12:00Z"))
{
    //selected date is greater than or equals to current date. Good to do code.
}
else
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being so quick. Solved my problem .

Comment: what "T12:00Z" does?

Comment: @SandeepBansal 21-05-2017 is not a valid Timestring. 21-05-2017T12:00 is. The Z stands for *Zulu* , you may have a deeper look at that as it can change many things...

Comment: Thanks for the info @Jonasw will have a look right away.

Comment: @Jonasw—the statement "*21-05-2017 is not a valid Timestring*" is misleading. It's a perfectly valid date, however it may not be correctly parsed by the built-in parser, but you should not rely on that at all.

Comment: Note that this will return false for many cases where it should return true, e.g. US time zones will return false until late afternoon or evening, even on the same date.